# Check if an exact number is in a range of row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have x numbers in column B. I want to check in a separate row that:
If the number Y is exactly the same in the column B. If yes, throw "Duplication" otherwise "Available".
I've tried `=IF(C2=B:B;"Duplication";"Number Available")`and the problem is that I always get "Duplication" if the cell C2 is empty and if the number inserted corresponds to the range of B column.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2;B:B;0));"Duplication";"Number Available")
```

[image]

Comment: I get FALSE even if the number isn't in B row. 
For instance I've put 1 in the search box and I still get false instead of Number Available

Comment: See edit for proof of it working.  Also I had a mistake in the original but edited it, make sure you are using the new one.

Comment: Perfect, @Scott Craner . Well done! Problem solved +1!